# How does LIBC_PROBE macro actually work in Glibc?

Tags: c, glibc

I was trying to understand how `mallopt()` works in glibc, but unable to understand the use of `LIBC_PROBE` macro used in the function `mallopt()`. The definition of `LIBC_PROBE` is creating another macro `LIBC_PROBE_1` and again it is creating another one `STAP_PROBE##n`. In case of `mallopt()` it is `STAP_PROBE3(a1, a2, a3)`. After this there no clue how `STAP_PROBE3` going to work ?
Source file: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c (line:5141).

Comment: can you paste the source in question or a link to it? the file name and line number in libc ?

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c. line number 5141.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `include/stap-probe.h`:

```
Without USE_STAP_PROBE, that does nothing but evaluates all
its arguments (to prevent bit rot, unlike e.g. assert).

Systemtap's header defines the macros STAP_PROBE (provider, name) and
STAP_PROBEn (provider, name, arg1, ..., argn).  For "provider" we paste
in MODULE_NAME (libc, libpthread, etc.) automagically.

The format of the arg parameters is discussed here:

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/UserSpaceProbeImplementation

The precise details of how register names are specified is
architecture specific and can be found in the gdb and SystemTap
source code.  */
```

So:

1. Don't worry about it -- it's not important for understanding how `malloopt()` works.
2. If you really care, read the wiki article referenced above, and look for how the macro is defined in SystemTap sources (SystemTap is entirely separate project from GLIBC).